# onLocationChanged gets called multiple times on start of application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, locationlistener, android-fusedlocation

I have written following service,The idea is to send User location to server on application launch and when user travels more than `500m`, The problem is that on launch it calls  `onLocationChanged` 3 times.

I am unable to understand that from where its calling it 3 times. Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem.

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {



    private static final long BACKGROUND_INTERVAL = 60000;

    final private String TAG = LocationUpdateService.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String LOCATION_PREF = "LOCATION_PREF";



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(BACKGROUND_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(500);
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("Location Service", "onLocationChanged: " + location.toString());
        saveLocationandReport(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot control `onLocationChanged`, it is manage by location service. In your case you can set a buffer/wait time, if you have location update within buffer time you can check its compare its accuracy with previous location update which ever is best use it.

```
private int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // use whatever suits you
private Location currentLocation = null;
private long locationUpdatedAt = Long.MIN_VALUE;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    boolean updateLocationandReport = false;
    if(currentLocation == null){
        currentLocation = location;
        locationUpdatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
        updateLocationandReport = true;
    } else {
       long secondsElapsed = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - locationUpdatedAt);
       if (secondsElapsed >= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(FASTEST_INTERVAL)){
            // check location accuracy here
            currentLocation = location;
            locationUpdatedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
            updateLocationandReport = true;
       }        
    }
    if(updateLocationandReport){
        //  send your location to server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't control when the onLocationChanged is called - it is the location service which calls it.

It may call if for a number of reasons - the most obvious is when the users actually moves and it detects this and sends you an update, but it also may be called when the location service gets a more accurate location.

As a general rule it takes a little time for an accurate location so if you need accuracy it may make sense to allow for this in your application.

Comment: Thanks, so do i need to trigger it lately? or Hit server on the third try, it always hit the service three times

Comment: use the accuracy parameter provided by the location object , then based on that u can decide what to do

Comment: @Ak9637 : getAccuracy returns 23.33 on all hits

Comment: then u can use some kind of buffer to check it the last few locations that u have recieved are different of more accurate or not

Comment: you can put logic in `saveLocationandReport` method to send location